# update attributes on session timeout rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, update-attributes

I'm trying to make an online user list by setting "1" to a db field when a user logs in, and "0", when he logs out. Trouble is - if a user just leaves the site, the "1" still stays in the db, so what I want to do is update it on session expire.

for login:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
      session[:username] = user.username
      remote_ip = request.remote_ip
      user.update_attributes(:online => 1, :ip => remote_ip) 
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end
```

and for logout:

```
 def destroy
    @user = User.where(:id => session[:user_id])
    @user.each do |u|
      u.update_attributes(:online => 0)
    end 
    session[:user_id] = nil
    session[:username] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

Can anybody suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it that way, because there's no way to guarantee that your `destroy` action will be called. What if the user loses his internet connection? Or the browser crashes? Or the user is AFK for the weekend?

The solution is to add a timestamp on the the `user` model, like `last_seen_at` and update that whenever the user performs an operation on your site, for example using a `before_filter`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :record_last_seen_at # TODO: Implement that method
end
```

Then if you want to list all online users, list all users active during the 5 last minutes, i.e. the users you *consider* online.

`User.where(['last_seen_at > ?', 5.minutes.ago])`

You could also use an existing authentication framework, like **[Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)** for example, and you'd get that feature for free.

Answer (score 0):

By use of the db set 1 or 0 login and logout is the bad way actually, also from the above answer using last_seen_at (devise usage) we will not get the active sessions list.

Please see this github sample app https://github.com/mohanraj-ramanujam/online-users to list online active sessions list with use of active record session store.